# Juggle among (possible) multiple internship interviews

Tags: internship

I will be required to perform a 3-month internship as part of course requirement this May to July. This internship can be self-sourced or secured under a window period (between late Jan to early Mar) facilitated by the university's career office, where students can submit multiple applications and receive multiple offers.

In the event that one receives an offer for a self-sourced internship, would it be ethical to communicate that one would like to consider the other internship opportunities that may arise (from the office window period)?

The concern is that it may not be reasonable for the company to wait for the candidate? given that the student has reached out to the company first?

Comment: I'm sure you can see how this would look bad to the self-sourced company: that they were your second choice in the first place, and you aren't enthusiastic and committed to working for them. You might get away with being non-specific about the dates you want to intern there, giving them options where you take another internship and where you don't, but at the point they offer you the role they'll likely want a decision from you. Is there no way to accelerate your 'window' applications so that you can apply to everyone in advance?

Comment: This is not much different from interviewing for several 'regular' jobs, so I'm voting to close as a duplicate. Many answers in that duplicate apply in your case.

Comment: One should avoid referring to oneself with silly pronouns.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly, let me state that you have to be very careful with your communication if you do intend to wait out the best opportunity.** If you mishandle the process you can potentially end up with no offers at all instead of several offers to choose from.

Additionally, would take some time to consider what reasons you might have to wait for the second offer in the first place. Unless you're getting desperate, you should begin with approaching companies you are interested in working with. Ideally it would even be companies that you can see yourself working at after you graduate since it is not unusual for an intern to get an offer of employment if they do well during their internship.

Following that reasoning, why would you ask such a company for more time to respond to their offer? Unless you're hoping for something better to come along, there's no reason not to take the offer in front of you. If there's still something about the offer that's not satisfactory, you should try to negotiate on that point if possible but if it's not something that's negotiable, you will probably have to decline that offer. The urge to have a 'safety net' or 'backup option' is understandable, but that really shouldn't come into play until the later stages of the process.

Also, remember that if you think there will be an interesting company presenting themselves during the window at your school, nothing prevents you from applying with them before the window! Unless they have an agreement with the school that they will only take a maximum of x interns from the school and that they will only make their selection during the school's provided window, there's no reason why you couldn't interview with them.

In this way, you can interview with all the intended companies in the same timeframe, lessening the risk of having to decline an offer from company A so you can wait for an offer (or even an interview opportunity) from company B. It's also much more acceptable to ask a company if you could have an extra week before you respond to their offer to allow you to carefully consider your options than it is to ask them to wait a month for interviews you might not even do.